# EXTJS 5 hide node in treegrid

Tags: extjs, tree, show-hide

Is there a way to hide a node (a parent or a child) in a treegrid? I set the visible property to false but it does not disappear: (here is the fiddle link: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/jl1)

```
var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    title: 'TreeGrid',
    width: 300,
    height: 250,
    fields: ['name', 'description'],
    columns: [{
        xtype: 'treecolumn',
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        width: 150,
        sortable: true
    }, {
        text: 'Description',
        dataIndex: 'description',
        flex: 1,
        sortable: true
    }],
    root: {
        expanded: true,
        children: [{
            name: 'Group 1',
            expanded: true,
            children: [{
                name: 'Child 1.1',
                description: 'Description 1.1',
                leaf: true
            },{
                name: 'Child 1.2',
                description: 'Description 1.2',
                leaf: true
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'Group 2',
            expanded: true,
            children: [{
                name: 'Child 2.1',
                description: 'Description 2.1',
                leaf: true
            },{
                name: 'Child 2.2',
                description: 'Description 2.2',
                leaf: true
            }]
        }]
    }
});

var button = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    text: 'Remove group 1',
    handler: function() {
        var group1 = tree.getRootNode().childNodes[0];
        group1.set('visible', false);
    }
});
```

Note: I don't want to remove the node, I want to hide it, to show it again later (I want to do this because the remove/add behaviour on tree grid is very bugged :S) !

Thanks in advance :) !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should work with tree store. Use filters to hide values from the tree.

I've fixed your fiddle. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/jl8 
I used `filterBy` method to fix it. If the function returns true the Record is included to a tree, otherwise it is filtered out.

Here is some more documentation about that topic http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore